# report records are in multiple systems

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Working in SQL I have a dataset of source systems and the ID of people who have access, simplified it looks like this:

| System | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Sys1 | A |
| Sys2 | A |
| Sys1 | B |
| sys2 | C |

What I want to get out is something like this:

| ID | Sys1 | Sys2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 |

I am sure someone has a solution to this here already, but my searching didn't turn up anything.

Comment: how many system (sys1, sys2, ...) you might have?

Comment: Right now only 4 for the preliminary study, but there are over 50 in the production system I will need to cover eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> create table mytable (Systems varchar(50),ID varchar(20));
> insert into  mytable values('Sys1','A');
> insert into  mytable values('Sys2','A');
> insert into  mytable values('Sys1','B');
> insert into  mytable values('sys2','C');
> ```

Query:

> ```
> select ID, sum(case when Systems='Sys1' then 1 else 0 end)Sys1,
>            sum(case when Systems='Sys2' then 1 else 0 end)Sys2
> From mytable
> Group by ID
> ```

Output:

> | ID | Sys1 | Sys2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 | 1 |
> | B | 1 | 0 |
> | C | 0 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d5017d67d3c023f7aac5f75b15b900a)*

Comment: The dataset will eventually expand to over 50 systems, and a total of IDs that fit each unique combination of system access will also be needed.  I was hoping there was a function I didn't know about to invert the datatable so I could subquery that within my main query that will build the aggregation of system accesses.

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Comment: have a look https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/pivot-in-sql.html

Comment: Thanks!  I am pretty sure this will get me where I need to go!

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes for the job.

Answer (score 0):

if it is limited to handful of system values  you can use this query:

```
select
  ID
  , MAX(case when system = 'Sys1' then 1 else 0 end) Sys1
  , MAX(case when system = 'Sys2' then 1 else 0 end) Sys2
  , MAX(case when system = 'Sys3' then 1 else 0 end) Sys3
  , MAX(case when system = 'Sys4' then 1 else 0 end) Sys4
  , ....
from table
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spark, why not leverage it's power. Read the data in a dataframe and then use:
`df.groupBy(col("ID")).pivot(col("System")).count().na.fill(0).show()`